# How to send data to php from angularjs and ionic

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-http

I am an angular begginer, and I am currently trying to save some data in a data base with the $http() service, but it does not work. Could you help me, please? This is what I am trying to do:

Form:

```html
<form name="form">
  <input ng-model="model.text" type="text" name="text">
  <button class="button" ng-click="saveData()"> Save </button>
</form>
```

Controller of that page:

```js
.controller('pagCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.saveData = function () {

    $http ({
        url : 'http://localhost/prueba/www/php/enviar_datos.php',
        method : 'POST',
        data : { text : $scope.form.text.value }
    }).then (function (response) {

    }, function (response) {

    });
  }
})
```

PHP:

```html
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testDB");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tabla_prueba (texto) VALUES ('" . $_POST['text'] . "')");
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I think the problem is that it does not connect correctly to the php url.
I am working with Ionic. Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

add `$scope.form.text={}` and in your js

`data:$.param($scope.form.text);`

and remove `ng-click` in button put `ng-submit` in form `ng-submit="saveData()"`

So you should rename your model . it hard to read.

```
ng-model="formData.text"
```

and in js

```
$scope.formData ={}
data:$.param($scope.formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable defined by the `ng-model` attribute.

```
<form name="form">
  <input ng-model="model.text" type="text" name="text">
  <button class="button" ng-click="saveData()"> Save </button>
</form>
```

```
app.controller('pagCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  //INITIALIZE model object
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.saveData = function () {

    $http ({
        url : 'http://localhost/prueba/www/php/enviar_datos.php',
        method : 'POST',
        //data : { text : $scope.form.text.value }
        //POST model object
        data: $scope.model

    }).then (function successHandler(response) {

    }, function rejectHandler(response) {

    });
  }
})
```

More inputs can be easily added with no change to the controller:

```
<form name="form">
  <input ng-model="model.text" type="text" name="text">
  <input ng-model="model.name" type="text" name="name">
  <input ng-model="model.id" type="text" name="id">
  <button class="button" ng-click="saveData()"> Save </button>
</form>
```

All inputs will be serialized and sent as a JSON string text.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, that was really useful

Comment: If that helped, please accept the answer. That lets other readers know the problem is solved. Also accepting answers gets you reputation points.